# How to open local files via firefox

Tags: php, firefox, localhost

I am having a php project in which I am basically dynamically creating hyperlinks to files existing on the local drive for eg c:/vikram/htc.doc . I created a basic html file and added the usual hyperlinks with the code as

hello

But whenever I launch this page in firefox, there is no response. It doesnt show an error message neither does it launch the file. When I checked the error console on firefox it reads.

Security Error: Content at http://localhost/PhpProject1/newhtml1.html may not load or link to file:///C:/vikram/htc.doc.

Even after implementing all their suggestions still firefox isnt allowing the file to be launched.

If anyone can please suggest me a way to work around this security feature or suggest another browser which allows this(I have tried IE too and it doesnt work there as well).
Since the php project is being launch via my xampp control of apache its redirected under localhost is there any way to work with this functionality.
PLease Help.

Comment: Why not move your doc file inside the www folder(or equivalent) of xampp? so that it can read from within the www folder itself. I am not sure if this is a solution, but its something which you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this issue by serving the files from the server itself. You can set up an alias to `c:/vikram` and then link to `http://localhost/vikram/htc.doc` from your webpage. More about setting up an alias in Apache: [Working With Apache’s Alias Directive](http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/apache-alias.html)

Comment: I cannot thank u enough!!!!!!

Comment: This worked like a charm!!!! I am very very grateful...i was goin over this for a couple of days now

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to not link to local files; have your web server serve them up.

The second-best way is to set some preferences to create a security hole in your web browser.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work explains how to do that.